# Laravel 5.4: How to get the same result without nesting one foreach inside another?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, foreach

What I intend is to get the news `$new` in a certain language `if($new_lang->lang_id == $lang_id)`, then I look in the table of images `@foreach($data['images'] as $image)` which corresponds to the news and which is the main one `@if($image->imageable_id == $new->id && $image->main == '1')`.

The problem is that when nesting foreachs, the load is very slow, since they are more than 7,000 news and some 70,000 images.

How to get the same result without nesting one foreach inside another?

```
@foreach($new->langs as $new_lang)
@if($new_lang->lang_id == $lang_id)
    @foreach($data['images'] as $image)
        @if($image->imageable_id == $new->id && $image->main == '1')
            @php
                $mini = substr($image->path, 0, strrpos( $image->path, "/"));
                $name = substr($image->path, strrpos($image->path, '/') + 1);
                $image_mini = $mini.'/mini-'.$name;
            @endphp
            <div class="crop">
                <a href="{{ route('noticia', [$new->id, $new_lang->slug]) }}">{{ HTML::image(file_exists($image_mini)? $image_mini : $image->path, '', array('class' => 'img-responsive ancho_100')) }}</a>
            </div>
        @endif
    @endforeach
@endif
@endforeach
```

**EDITED:** added controller and trait

This is the controller:

```
    use ListNoticias;

public function actualidad(Request $request)
{
    $data['section_id'] = explode(',', '1,2,3');

    $data['ruta'] = 'actualidad';
    $data['title'] = __('header.actualidad');
    $data['num'] = $request->num;
    $url = $request->url();

    $data = $this->listNoticias($data, $url);

    return view('web.actualidad.listado', compact('data'));
}
```

And the trait:

```
trait ListNoticias
{
public function listNoticias($data, $url)
{
    $now = date('Y-m-d');
    $time = date('H:i:s');

    (isset($data['num']))? $num = $data['num'] : $num = '15';

    $data['images'] = Image::where('imageable_type', 'App\Models\Noticia')->get();
    $data['sections']  = Section::all();

    $data['noticias'] = Noticia::with('langs')->where('date', '<', $now)
        ->where('active', '1')
        ->whereIn('section_id', $data['section_id'])
        ->orWhere('date', '=', $now)
        ->where('time', '<=', $time)
        ->where('active', '1')
        ->whereIn('section_id', $data['section_id'])
        ->orderBy('date', 'desc')
        ->orderBy('time', 'desc')
        ->get();

    $data['noticias-es'] = [];
    $data['noticias-en'] = [];
    $data['noticias-pt'] = [];

    foreach($data['noticias'] as $row){
        foreach($row->langs as $row_lang) {
            if ($row_lang->lang_id == '1') {
                $data['noticias-es'][] = $row;
            } elseif ($row_lang->lang_id == '2') {
                $data['noticias-en'][] = $row;
            } elseif ($row_lang->lang_id == '3') {
                $data['noticias-pt'][] = $row;
            } else null;

        }
    }

    // Manual paginate
    /*  Get current page form url e.x. &page=1
        Create a new Laravel collection from the array data
        Slice the collection to get the items to display in current page
        Create our paginator and pass it to the view
        set url path for generated links
    */

    $currentPage = LengthAwarePaginator::resolveCurrentPage();

    // ES
    $itemCollection = collect($data['noticias-es']);
    $currentPageItems = $itemCollection->slice(($currentPage * $num) - $num, $num)->all();
    $data['noticias-es'] = new LengthAwarePaginator($currentPageItems , count($itemCollection), $num);
    $data['noticias-es']->setPath($url);

    // EN
    $itemCollection = collect($data['noticias-en']);
    $currentPageItems = $itemCollection->slice(($currentPage * $num) - $num, $num)->all();
    $data['noticias-en'] = new LengthAwarePaginator($currentPageItems , count($itemCollection), $num);
    $data['noticias-en']->setPath($url);

    // PT
    $itemCollection = collect($data['noticias-pt']);
    $currentPageItems = $itemCollection->slice(($currentPage * $num) - $num, $num)->all();
    $data['noticias-pt'] = new LengthAwarePaginator($currentPageItems , count($itemCollection), $num);
    $data['noticias-pt']->setPath($url);

    return $data;

}
}
```

**EDITED 2**

The first view is a partial and is included in this view that have another two foreach nestead. This is because I need to display records in threes. I have commented on other includes that are not necessary for the problem:

```
@foreach ($data['noticias-'.$lang]->chunk(3) as $chunk)

<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 pad_inf_2">

    @foreach($chunk as $key => $new)
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 pad_der_1">
            <article>
                //@include('web.index.partials.noticia_etiqueta')
                @include('web.actualidad.partials.noticia_image_listado')
                //@include('web.index.partials.noticia_date_section')
                //@include('web.index.partials.noticia_title')
            </article>
        </div>
    @endforeach

</div>
@endforeach
```

Model Noticia:

```
class Noticia extends Model
{
protected $fillable = ['section_id', 'active', 'date', 'time', 'author'];

public function images()
{
    return $this->morphMany('App\Models\Image', 'imageable');
}

public function tags()
{
    return $this->morphToMany('App\Models\Tag', 'taggable');
}

public function section()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Section');
}

public function langs()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\LangNoticia');
}

}
```

LangNoticia Model:

```
class LangNoticia extends Model
{
protected $fillable = ['noticia_id', 'lang_id', 'title', 'lead', 'text', 'author_place', 'slug'];

public function noticia()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Noticia');
}
}
```

**EDITED 3**: Reduced code in the trait with the advices of **abr**

Trait reduced:

```
trait ListNoticias
{
public function listNoticias($data, $url)
{
    $lang = Session::get('lang');
    if($lang == 'en') $lang_id = '2';
    elseif($lang == 'pt') $lang_id = '3';
    else $lang_id = '1';

    $now = date('Y-m-d');
    $time = date('H:i:s');

    (isset($data['num']))? $num = $data['num'] : $num = '15';

    $data['sections']  = Section::all();
    $data['images'] = Image::where('imageable_type', 'App\Models\Noticia')->where('main', true)->get();

    $noticias = Noticia::with('langs')
        ->where('date', '<', $now)
        ->where('active', '1')
        ->whereIn('section_id', $data['section_id'])
        ->orWhere('date', '=', $now)
        ->where('time', '<=', $time)
        ->where('active', '1')
        ->whereIn('section_id', $data['section_id'])
        ->orderBy('date', 'desc')
        ->orderBy('time', 'desc')
        ->get();

    $data['noticias-'.$lang] = [];

    foreach($noticias as $row){
        foreach($row->langs as $row_lang) {
            if ($row_lang->lang_id == $lang_id) {
                $data['noticias-'.$lang][] = $row;
            }
        }
    }

    // Paginate
    /*  Get current page form url e.x. &page=1
        Create a new Laravel collection from the array data
        Slice the collection to get the items to display in current page
        Create our paginator and pass it to the view
        set url path for generated links
    */

    $currentPage = LengthAwarePaginator::resolveCurrentPage();

    $itemCollection = collect($data['noticias-'.$lang]);
    $currentPageItems = $itemCollection->slice(($currentPage * $num) - $num, $num)->all();
    $data['noticias-'.$lang] = new LengthAwarePaginator($currentPageItems , count($itemCollection), $num);
    $data['noticias-'.$lang]->setPath($url);

    return $data;

}
}
```

Comment: Can you show the controller method that calls the view?

Comment: Yes, I have already updated.

Comment: Do you have a relationship between `Noticia` and `Image`?

Comment: Yes I have, Camilo. I have updated again because I have seen that information was missing (EDITED 2)

Comment: A `Noticia` has several `images`

Comment: I would try including the images relationship when querying for the news instead of separately querying for all images and then match the corresponding news.

Comment: I've thought about that before but I have not known how to do it.

Comment: Can you show the relationships of the `LangNoticia` model?

Comment: I have updated.

Answer (score 1):

Just sharing some thoughts on it. Starting with retrieving the content of `Noticias`:

Do you really need all these 3 languages? Are there going to be more in the future? Is it only a segment of these 'Noticias' that you want to show?

Answering these questions you should come up with:

1. A way to, in the eventuality of adding another language, you won't have to alter the function;
2. A way to increase the query performance, because fetching 7k records is different from recording the 7k x 154 languages
3. Do you really need all 7k?

You can, for example, split that query up into several (if you really require all languages) or validate it with an advanced function within your Eager Loading statement.

```
Noticia::with(['langs' => function ($query) {
    //where this lang_id == 1, select it as whatever name you require
}])
.
.
.
```

Second is, are you sure you want those wheres exactly how they are? You're not filtering much with orWhere or Where. If you plan on narrowing down the search, I advice having a function on your where statement, just like the example shown above.
If you'd like to see what the query is all about, write:

```
dd($data['noticias']->toSql());
```

Getting the images for all those news is going to be heavy, if you claim to have 70k over 7k news. You don't need to really load everything out of the start, you can use a simple `->paginate(15);` to narrow it down, along side a `->skip(15);`

Comment: Thanks abr, I will follow what you tell me and I tell you the results... if I am able to do it ;)

Comment: Hi @abr following your advice, I have reduced the code a lot by obtaining the language of a session variable. Will not grow in languages beyond 4. I am using a manual paging because I have to create the array according to the language and I can not use 'paginate()' What I do not know how to do is the query that you propose, because I do not have enough knowledge. Could you explain how to do it? I updated the question with the trait reduced in EDITED 3

Comment: If you can, leave a basic structure of your table (or tables that you require info from) and the desired json output, and I'll do my best to help you when I get home, can't atm

Comment: Thanks @abr for your arrangement! More or less, I solved with your advice and those of Camilo. I'm a bit stressed by the imminent publication of the project, so for now I'm going to leave it that way. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can access the news main image like this:

```
$new_lang->noticia->images()->where('main', true)->first();
```

You could define an [accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor) in your `LangNoticia` model to facilitate the call.

```
public function getImageAttribute()
{
    return $this->noticia->images()->where('main', true)->first();
}
```

In your view you can remove the `foreach()` and call the accessor instead.

```
@foreach($new->langs as $new_lang)
    @if($new_lang->lang_id == $lang_id)
        @php
            $mini = substr($new_lang->image->path, 0, strrpos( $new_lang->image->path, "/"));
            $name = substr($new_lang->image->path, strrpos($new_lang->image->path, '/') + 1);
            $image_mini = $mini.'/mini-'.$name;
        @endphp
        <div class="crop">
            <a href="{{ route('noticia', [$new->id, $new_lang->slug]) }}">{{ HTML::image(file_exists($image_mini)? $image_mini : $new_lang->image->path, '', array('class' => 'img-responsive ancho_100')) }}</a>
        </div>
    @endif
@endforeach
```

Now you can remove the call to the `Image` model in your trait.

Use [eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) when querying the `Noticia` model to reduce the number of queries.

```
Noticia::with(['images' => function($query) {
    $query->where('main', true);
}])->get();
```

Comment: Thanks Camilo! This seem interesting. I have not used the accessor before, I'm going to work on it and I tell you.

Comment: I´m doing something wrong defining or calling the accessor. In `LangNoticia`I put: `public function getImageAttribute($value)
    {
        return ucfirst($value->noticia->images()->where('main', true)->first());
    }` And in the view: `@if($new_lang->image)` and this give me the error: **Trying to get property of non-object** The error is in `LangNoticia`

Comment: I don't think you need the `$value` parameter in this case. I updated my answer with an example.

Comment: Thanks Camilo! This works well. I have learned a new thing :) The only drawback is that for this particular case, it slows down the load more. Using the foreach, it gives me a result of 4 queries and using the accessor gives me a result of 33 queries. So even nesting two foreachs, finally it's faster. I am optimizing the trait and have if I find an alternative perhaps to the two foreachs that create the list of three in three to reduce the loading time.

Comment: To reduce the number of queries you can use [eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) when querying the `Noticia` model.

Comment: @nature Added more examples to my answer.